# What is the optimal way to start python scripts in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

Since opening a console and typing `"long\path\interpreter\python.exe" "long\path\project\script.py"` or `py "long\path\project\script.py"` is bothersome, what's the best way so start a script?

The ones I have come up with:

- putting the text in a bat script
- copying the script to the folder
- shortcut to the script
- mklink soft and hard to the script from the folder

Comment: Add Python executable to Window's Path variable

Comment: Or just run any scripts within whatever IDE you use directly.

Comment: If you don't need the primary action for .py files to open an editor, then you can use the "open with" dialog on the context menu of a .py file to associate Python scripts with the installed "Python.File" progid. If the launcher is installed, it should be the Python icon with a rocket on the Python logo. Select to always use this app. Add ".PY" to the `PATHEXT` environment variable, if it's not already added, and save the script in a directory that's in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Now, to run "script.py", just enter `script` in the command prompt. The shell will search each `PATH` directory for "script.COM", "script.EXE", "script.BAT", and so on up to "script.PY". CMD will try to run "script.py" first via `CreateProcessW`, which will fail with access denied if the file doesn't grant you execute access, but other errors such as bad filetype (it's a script, not a PE image) are handled by trying `ShellExecuteExW` which will execute the default template command for .PY files, e.g. as set by the "Python.File" progid.

Answer (score -1):

bat/shell scripts are usually the best way. If this is a script you'll be using often, you can also save the path to an environment var in cmd so you can just call something like `python %MY_PATH%/script.py`

Answer (score -1):

Windows Search => environment variable => PATH => Add your Python Installation

or while installing python on Windows check the Box for adding Python to Path.

now you can just use python yourscript.py or python3 yourscript.py